# Using counter within an "---[]" expression in vba

Tags: vba, webforms

I have a macro that enters data from Excel in a web form. it looks like this:
`IE.document.all("substance[1][1]").Value = Cells(i, 6).Value`

For every row that I add, the expression in [ ] changes. Is there a way to automate this? Something like:
`IE.document.all("substance[n][m]").Value = Cells(i, 6).Value`
so I can write at the end of the loop `n=n+1`?
Cheers

Here's the full code:

```
Sub BOMcheckAutoEingabe()
Dim IE As Object
Dim Login As String
Dim Passwort As String
Dim row As Integer
row = 22
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    ShowWindow IE.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
    .Navigate "https://demo.bomcheck.net/de/"
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
    Loop
    IE.document.all("username").Value = "****"
    IE.document.all("password").Value = "****"
    IE.document.all("Submit").Click
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    .Navigate "https://demo.bomcheck.net/de/parts/addfullmaterialsdeclaration" _
    & "#fmd-table"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    SendKeys "{TAB 6}", True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    If Sheets("FMD).Cells(row, 1) <> 0 Then
        IE.document.all("usage[1]").Value = Cells(row, 1).Value
    Else
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: try this `IE.document.all("substance["&n&"]["&m&"]").Value`

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work - syntax error :(

Comment: show your full code please or part related to issue

Comment: just edited the question with the partially full code.

Comment: Showing the relevant HTML would have improved this as an [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

as already posted in comments to OP, here the test of proposed solution

```
Sub test()
Dim n As Long, m As Long, Check As String
m = 1
For n = 1 To 10
    Check = "substance[" & n & "][" & m & "]"
    Debug.Print Check
Next n
End Sub
```

which is give you this

[image]

just follow this logic within your code

Comment: it doesn't seem to work with:
`IE.document.all("usage[1]").Value = Cells(row, 1).Value` 
running the script with
`IE.document.all("usage["&n&"]").Value = Cells(row, 1).Value`
returns syntax error...

Comment: You forgot spaces, must be `IE.document.all("usage[" & n & "]").Value`

Comment: i'll give it another shot---

Comment: did you assign value to variable `n` before using in `IE.document.all("usage[" & n & "]").Value` ?

Comment: I declared `n`as integer and assigned `n = 1`

Comment: problem must not be associated with proposed solution due to the string will be the same string, no matter how it will be written, `"usage[1]"` or will be `"usage[" & n & "]"` with `n = 1`, it will return exactly the same meaning `usage[1]`

Answer (score 0):

converting to String solved the problem:

this one does the trick:

`IE.document.all("usage[" + CStr(t) + "]").Value = Cells(zeile, 1).Value`